# If Ado.Net is "outdated" then why is it that everyone still uses it in solutions with sql?

Tags: ado.net

I was having a discussion the other day in regards to connecting to databases and using stored procedures and such, then I was told that Ado.Net is outdated and not really being used, but everywhere you look for solutions on connecting with SQL or interacting with SQL that everyone is still using Ado. I was told that the days of using Ado is long gone and now its entity framework that is being widely used. Is this because fewer people are learning Ado? Or is it for a separation of programmers and Sql developers?

Comment: Well i never heard Ado.NET was outdated/deprecated

Comment: That's what I was told the other day, that its outdated and that I'm doing it the old school way

Comment: If you're using EF there's still Ado.NET under it. Anyway, EF is an ORM which can be better in some case, depends on what project you have to do

Comment: I've never used EF, so I wouldn't know when using it would be of any benefit. I've always used sqlconnection and command objects, and never thought any different of it, until I was having that discussion.